# Is this site for Children?

Tags: minor-katan-child, mistakes, chinuch-education, stackexchange

A father asked me if this site is appropriate for children considering the fact that oftentimes incorrect answers are being posted. Children are very impressionable and as *Chazal* tell us, *Shabeshtah, Kavun D'ul, Ul.* , a mistake, once it takes hold, it stays. I understand that in theory, given the guideline of providing sources for the answers there shouldn't be mistaken answers, but we cannot control this. So what do you think?

Comment: Why isn't this on meta?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Because this question was posted on mi.yodeya before judaism.SE launched its beta and before there *was* a meta.

Comment: @DoubleAA, this a question of _halacha_ or _hashkafa_, so it belongs on this site. That's my opinion: if you differ, vote to close it. (If you choose the "off topic" reason, you'll be offered the option of voting to move the question to the meta site.)

Comment: Can't it be moved to meta?

Comment: I'm not so sure if a child would be very interested in visiting this site and reading a bunch of boring questions and answers. There's a lot more "more interesting" sites on the web a child would rather visit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on meta.

Comment: @DoubleAA Can this be moved to Meta?

Comment: @donie not sure. I recommend you flag for mod attention explain what you want and why

Comment: @DonielF it's too old to migrate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it depends on the child and is entirely up to the parents' judgement, consistent with their general policies on Internet access and on Halacha learning (1). Hopefully, all parents these days are teaching their kids not to believe everything they read on the Internet (or in real life for that matter) and skills for gauging the credibility of information.

Of course, one option available would be for the parents to participate here as well and pay attention to what their kids are participating in and to topics that their kids might be reading about, so that the parents can provide correction (publicly or privately) in areas that need it.

I do hope that people understand the responsibility they take on themselves when they write an answer (or even a question) in public. You never know who's going to read it (child or adult, Jewishly experienced or not), but the better job you do at making it accurate, humble, well-backed-up by sources, and clear, the better chance that they will come away enlightened rather than confused.

"Scholars, be careful with your words!" - Avtalyon, in [Avot 1](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2165/jewish/Chapter-One.htm):11

---

1) As I've mentioned [before](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/409/make-for-yourself-a-website/414#414), formal Torah classes can also give people the wrong impression or prompt them to action that may not be appropriate for them. And, the authority status of the teacher makes these impressions potentially stronger.

2) As an aside, I've gotten a little excited about mi.yodeya's utility as a kosher place on the Internet for young Jews to frequent:

- Lots of Torah learning.
- Engages their curiosity.
- Highly interactive, almost in real-time.
- Dignifies simple questions with serious answers from serious, smart people.
- Practical education in clear writing and web interaction.
- Moderated for content, but not heavy-handedly.
- There are no private spaces. No private messaging. No sharing of contact info. No [yichud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yichud). Every interaction here is visible to parents and the public.

Comment: Isaac, you've done it again! I hope you understand that I am playing "devil's advocate" with these type of questions to see what will be articulated. You have not disappointed me!

Comment: Yahu, Thanks very much! Your meta questions advocate for anything but "the devil," and I very much appreciate the opportunity to think about and respond to them.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if a child goes on this web site, he should be accompanied by a learned adult who can guide him through the right answers & questions.