# On a boat in the Arctic Circle

Tags: halacha, shabbat, zemanim, geography

I and my wife will be spending Shabbat Hagadol (this year the 31st of March) on a ship. The evening before the ship will be leaving one of the more northern ports of Norway, and navigating through fjords on that Saturday before emerging just north of Trondheim as the sun goes down. The internet says that three stars will be visible from Hammerfest at 9:29pm, after a sunset longer than is halachically thought possible. But I am also aware of the halachic indecision when it comes to observance of the Jewish calendar in the polar regions. So specifically, what times do I observe when the ship leaves port on Friday evening (in the polar region), whether or not I know my ship will be traveling far enough south to make a halachic difference on Shabbat?

Comment: DJRosenschein, Welcome to judaism.SE and thanks for the fascinating question. Please note, though, that [this site is not meant for practical halachic guidance](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/409/make-for-yourself-a-website); a competent Rav must be consulted. Because of this, it is preferred that halachic questions be phrased theoretically. Answers will contain information and sources useful in making halachic decision, but no actual halachic decision. That said, enjoy the site, and hang around to ask/answer more questions.

Comment: DJ Rosenschein, per jake's excellent comment, do you think you could reword your question to be relevant to a more general scenario? I am closing it as a temporary measure until that's done; comment here with `@msh210` after you've generalized it and I will be glad to reopen it.

Comment: Related to but not duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7182 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8282.

Comment: So a better, more general wording is this: How does one figure out the timing of Shabbat on a boat north of the Arctic Circle?