# Can there be kiddushin between a Ger Toshav and a Jew?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, shulchan-aruch, kiddushin-eirusin, responsa

I came across [an article](https://www.sefaria.org.il/sheets/126652.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that quoted Rabbi Yitzchak Yosef in his *Shulchan Ha'ma'arechet*, (it didn't give an exact reference,) as saying that *Kiddushin* can be effected between a *Ger Toshav*, meaning a non-Jew who follows the 7 Noahide commandments and a Jew, because a *Ger Toshav* is considered not to worship idols. First of all is this correct and secondly are there any other authorities who either hold, or dispute this view? Please give sources if known.

Comment: Sounds very unlikely to me. Do you have a link to the article?

Comment: It was from the Sefaria.org website linked to a "sheet" but I don't have a link and at the time didn't note the author. I think it was in connection with an opinion given by Rabbi Amichai Lau-Lavie. The given quotation from Rav Yosef is; "Kiddushin are not effective with a non-Jewish woman, because it is written "do not make marriages with them [for doing so will turn away your son from following Me, that they may serve other gods]." But with a ger toshav woman, since there is no prohibition of "do not make marriages with them" [because they do not serve other gods], kiddushin are effective."

Comment: Found it. The Sheet is called: Rabbi Amichai Lau Lavi's Teshuvah on Intermarriage:
A source primer by Jeremy Borovitz.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/126652

Comment: @Kleinzahler See here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101627/according-to-the-halakhah-is-marriage-forbidden-between-israelites-and-noahides

Comment: @Amos74 Thanks for the link. Thanks also to Rabbi Greenberg. I followed the links in your reply and with some extra research found out more about Rabbi Lau-Lavie.

Comment: @Kleinzahler You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Steve Greenberg [writes](http://www.rabbiswithoutborders.net/ss43.html)

> The marriage of a Jew and a ger toshav would not be legitimate under
> existing halachic frameworks.

[Some](https://forward.com/opinion/373982/conservative-jewish-intermarriage-renegade-rabbi/) conservative Rabbis are considering the possibility of allowing the marriage.

> Lau-Lavie is not the first to suggest adapting this construct to
> marriage, and his proposal is not meant to push for an actual change
> in Jewish law (yet). But he envisions using the ger toshav within a
> halachic framework to justify intermarriage under certain conditions.