# R Yitzchak Yosef on kiddushin with ger toshav

Tags: sources-mekorot, conversion-to-judaism, kiddushin-eirusin

Page 31 of [this paper](https://amichai.me/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Welcome_Book_2017.pdf) gives a Hebrew extract from Shulchan ha-Ma’arechet by R Yitzchak Yosef, in which the author argues that kiddushin is possible between a Jew and a ger toshav. Apparently it comes in a section of the book about Uriah the Hittite.

But… I can’t find the quote in the original at all. Nor, indeed, can I find anything about Uriah the Hittite. Can anyone help?

(A similar question was previously asked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/122426/can-there-be-kiddushin-between-a-ger-toshav-and-a-jew) but without access to the actual Hebrew text of the quote.)

Answer (score 3):

The quote is not from R. Yosef's שולחן המערכת, it is from a subsection of the מוריה journal titled **מ**שלחן המערכת.

It's on p. 138 ofמוריה שנה עשרים וארבע  גליון ז-ט סיון תשס”ב   and available under Book ID 108133 on Otzar at p.295. The section appears to be write-ins commenting on previously submitted content. In this case, the commenter is רב חיים מרדכי שפירא from רמת שלמה ירושלים.

Good catch... it's definitely a good lesson on checking primary sources cited in secondary sources.

[image]